# How to take the output of Sys.command as string in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, I have this piece of code:

```
let s =Sys.command ("minisat test.txt | grep 'SATIS' ");;
```

I want to take the output of minisat test.txt | grep "SATIS" , which is SATISFIABLE/UNSATISFIABLE to the string s.

I am getting the following output:

```
SATISFIABLE   
val s : int = 0
```

So, how can I make the output of this command to a string.

Also, is it possible to even import time?

This is the output I get when I try `minisat test.txt` in terminal

```
WARNING: for repeatability, setting FPU to use double precision
============================[ Problem Statistics ]=============================
|                                                                             |
|  Number of variables:             5                                         |
|  Number of clauses:               3                                         |
|  Parse time:                   0.00 s                                       |
|  Eliminated clauses:           0.00 Mb                                      |
|  Simplification time:          0.00 s                                       |
|                                                                             |
============================[ Search Statistics ]==============================
| Conflicts |          ORIGINAL         |          LEARNT          | Progress |
|           |    Vars  Clauses Literals |    Limit  Clauses Lit/Cl |          |
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
restarts              : 1
conflicts             : 0              (-nan /sec)
decisions             : 1              (0.00 % random) (inf /sec)
propagations          : 0              (-nan /sec)
conflict literals     : 0              (-nan % deleted)
Memory used           : 8.00 MB
CPU time              : 0 s

SATISFIABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use just Sys, you can't.

However, you can create a temporary file (see the `Filename` module's documentation [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Filename.html)) and tell the command to output in it:

```
let string_of_command () =
 let tmp_file = Filename.temp_file "" ".txt" in
 let _ = Sys.command @@ "minisat test.txt | grep 'SATIS' >" ^ tmp_file in
 let chan = open_in tmp_file in
 let s = input_line chan in
 close_in chan;
 s
```

Note that this function is drafty: you have to properly handle potential errors happening. Anyway, you can adapt it to your needs I guess.

You can avoid the temporary file trick by using the `Unix` library or more advanced libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me if we can export time also?

Comment: What do you mean by "export time" ?

Comment: I want the program to take the answer about satisfiability along with time taken

Comment: You can output without the grep and read the file with any parsing way you prefer (in the stdlib Genlex could do the trick, ocamllex or Str would also probably allow you to do that)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Unix.open_process_in` or `Unix.create_process`, if you want to capture the output.

Or better use a higher level wrapper like 'shell' (from ocamlnet):
http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-4.0.2/doc/html-main/Shell_intro.html

But I wouldn't pipe it to grep (not portable). Parse the output with your favorite regex library inside OCAML.